# Add a progress bar for SNOPT solver in pydrake

Tags: python, drake

I am using the `AddVisualizationCallback` functionality for pydrake `MathematicalProgram` objects to try and make a progress bar that I can update while the solver is running, so that I can see how my solver is doing without having to look at the overly verbose output coming from SNOPT (which BTW I haven't been able to print to console, only to file). My approach would be something like this:

```
import pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram as mp
from tqdm import tqdm

prog = mp.MathematicalProgram()

pbar = tqdm(total=max_iterations)
def update(x):
    pbar.update(1)
prog.AddVisualizationCallback(update, x)
```

However, my problem is SNOPT has both major and minor iterations, and it seems my `update` callback gets called irrespective of it being major or minor. Ideally, I would like it to be called only on a major iteration, otherwise my progress bar will fill sooner than it should.

My question: is there a way to tell whether a particular iteration is a major or minor iteration of SNOPT, such that I could provide that information to my `update` callback and only update my progress bar on the major iteration? Alternatively, could I set it so that the visualization callback is ONLY called on major iterations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've managed to hack together a solution using the log file that is written by SNOPT:

```
from tqdm import tqdm
import pydrake.solvers.mathematicalprogram as mp
from pydrake.solvers.snopt import SnoptSolver

prog = mp.MathematicalProgram()

fmax_iterations = 20
log_filename = '/tmp/snopt.out'
log = open(log_filename, 'w+')
pbar = tqdm(total=max_iterations)

def update(x):
    lines = log.read()
    if 'Itns Major Minors' in lines:
        idx = lines.rfind('Itns Major Minors')
        header, info = lines[idx:].split('\n')[:2]
        for name, val in zip(header.split(), info.split()):
            if name == 'Major':
                pbar.n = int(val)
                pbar.refresh()
                break

prog.AddVisualizationCallback(update, x)

solver_options = mp.SolverOptions()
solver_options.SetOption(mp.CommonSolverOption.kPrintFileName, log_filename)
solver_options.SetOption(SnoptSolver.id(), "Major iterations limit", max_iterations)
solver_options.SetOption(SnoptSolver.id(), "Print frequency", 1)

result = mp.Solve(prog, solver_options=solver_options)
pbar.n = max_iterations
pbar.refresh()
pbar.close()
log.close()
```

This gives me a nice progress bar while the SNOPT solver is running without all the clutter it's actually printing to its log file:

```
40%|██████████████▍                     | 8/20 [00:07<00:11,  1.07it/s]
```

It'd be nice to have a programmatic hook into the solver in the callback function, maybe that's possible? Short of that, this seems to do the job.